# Pass a string from ASPX to a ASCX

Tags: asp.net, .net, ascx

What I'm trying to do is send a string from ASPX to the code behind of a UserControl.

The first step works, and calls a WS and brings back a string.

**ASPX**

```
function (data) {
            //UpdateUserControl!
    };
```

The issue is that I have no idea how to pass this string on to a UserControl, I tried a __doPostBack but that only refreshes the whole page. I just want to update a listbox with the items. With the intention of later retrieving a string from the User Control. I am using a UpdatePanel in my UserControl.

**ASCX.VB**

```
'Get shopping list
Public Function UpdateList(list As String) As ListBox
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim strItems As String = list
    Dim strArray As String() = strItems.Split(","c)
    For Each item As String In strArray
        myListBox.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    Return email_add
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to the code behind of the usercontrol. You can then set the value from the containing page.

Comment: I have that, a public property, but can I set that from ASPX? I can update it from the ASPX code-behind, but not ASPX itself.

Comment: After some more research I don't think it's possible to update a UserControl directly from ASPX, unless you can pass the value back to the ASPX code-behind. I'll figure out another way of updating the UC.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

In aspx

```
public string yourvalue { get; set; }
```

then ascx.cs

```
 _Default d = new _Default();
  string s = d.yourvalue;
```

sure its working.

Comment: Ah, that's what I already had. I just wanted to pass a value from javascript in ASPX to the UserControl, I can do a post-back but that does a full-page refresh.. or I could load the data into a hidden field but that seems really messy.